# Pulling from private repositories using sbt

Tags: git, sbt, uri, bitbucket

I am trying to pull a particular branch from a private repository on bitbucket

This works but asks for username and password.

```
val projectname = uri("https://bitbucket.org/username/projectname.git#branchname")
```

I'd prefer the ssh route to avoid entering username and password, (also for automated build processes).

```
 val projectname = uri("git@bitbucket.org:username/projectname.git#branchname")
```

But I get this error on trying to run that.

```
[error] java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 3: git@bitbucket.org:username/projectname.git#branchname
```

However, I can clone the same project using

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/projectname.git#branchname
```

Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Does it work if you use `git://git@bitbucket.org...`?

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. Nor does this one `ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/projectname.git#branchname`

In fact, that url format doesn't even work with a `git clone` command.

Answer (score 0):

The url format was wrong. This one works.

```
 val projectname = uri("ssh://git@bitbucket.org/username/projectname.git#branchname")
```

Thanks to @jsuereth for the suggestion.

Comment: Just wanted to emphasize the existence of colon ":" between bitbucket.com and the username which causes the issue. Anyone using ssh:// to clone the bitbucket repo must remove that one.